# Using { get; set; } normally and with arrays, in object oriented development

Tags: c#, .net

I learned about following syntax today

```
 protected String TaskTitle { get; set; }
```

If I am correct this essentially translates to something like:

```
String _taskTitle;
protected String TaskTitle {
    get { return _taskTitlel }
    set { _taskTitle = value; }
}
```

My question is how can we use it now with objects to set and get certain values? Lets assume object is named `MyTest(String title)` how would I set `TaskTitle` equal to a passed in argument `title`? and afterwards instead of having methods like `.getTitle(..)` `.setTitle(..)` how would I take advantage of this `{get; set;}` syntax?

I understand that this might be getting long, but I believe this "sub question" belongs here, can I use this for arrays? Lets assume I have other object named `MyTestTwo(String title, String description, int number);` That inherits from first one, and I'd like to have an array `MyTestTwo[] { get; set; }` as part of `MyTest()` object, how could I populate it?

I know this might be a lot to ask, but I want to understand this {get; set;} syntax as I am new to it and new to c# in general, so far documentation is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: `someObject.TaskTitle = "hello world"` for setters or `var x = someObject.TaskTitle` for getters.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are after but as you say the first syntax is effectively the same as the second except that you cannot access `_taskTitle` so you would use it in the exact same way (ie `TaskTitle=title;` or whatever.

Comment: if **MyTest** a constructor?

Comment: @HackerMan yeah as well as class name in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark your property `public` to 'see' it in classes that do not derive your current class.

You can set it like this then:

```
yourInstance.TaskTitle = "test 123";
```

As an answer on your second question:

You can populate the array like you normally would when using variables:

```
yourInstance.ArrayProperty = new string[1];
yourInstance.ArrayProperty[0] = "test 123";
```

Comment: True, thanks! forgot to change it after experimenting with other stuff.

Comment: So say to use this with arrays In my case I could add / set objects to it like MyTest.ArrayName[0] = MyTestTwo("title", "description", 3); and than to get something specific from it I'd use MyTest.ArrayName[0].SomeProperty (is this more or less the idea?)

Answer (score 0):

in C# you use the properties by either getting the value via a `string a = class.TaskTitle;` or setting via `class.TaskTitle = "foo"`;

As far as array objects, try this:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 foo.bar = new Bar[5];
 foo.bar[0] = new Bar();
 foo.bar[1] = new Bar();
 ...
```

After which you can access the properties of the Bar via the same syntax as any other object:

```
foo.bar.SomeMethod();
```

Or, sans nested classes:

```
Foo[] foo = new Foo[2];
foo[0] = new Foo();
foo[1] = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{ get; set; }` syntax like this to modify properties on existing objects:

```
myTest.TaskTitle = "A brand new title";
```

And like this to read data from existing objects

```
string currentTitle = mytest.TaskTitle;
```

Additionally you can use the following shorthand syntax to initialize a new object:

```
MyTest myTest = new MyTest{ TaskTitle = "a new task"};
```

There's some other shorthand syntax you can use for initializing ICollection data structures, which is explained quite well here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming this is your constructor

```
   MyTest(String title)
{
TaskTitle=title;
}
Modifier returntype PropertyName
{
get;
set;
}
```

**get** and **set** are methods ....in c# we use them becouse they are compact and simple.

or you can use  methods get and set by creating in your class separately...like

```
public returntype get()
{

return yourPrivateMember;//
}

public returntype set(type value)
{

yourPrivateMember=value;//in certain cases you dont want the user the mess your private variable and you can control how the user interacts with your private variables
}
```